# Create OCSP Request manually in Node

Tags: node.js, ocsp

I don't want to use this library (https://github.com/indutny/ocsp), because it makes some assumptions about my certificates that are non-standard.

Assuming I have the hashes I need, I was wondering how I use the `https.request function` in order to create a OCSP request manually. Basically, what fields are necessary in the OCSP Request object you pass into `https.request`?

The internet seems fuzzy on what the body should look like.

Comment: if you don't want to use ready solutions, then you have to write your own. There is a documentation on OCSP: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6960

Comment: I would just look on ocsp sources to get such an info, also this can be helpful:
https://dzone.com/articles/ocsp-validation-with-openssl

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out? I am tryiing to do this same thing right now.